# Как сделать бесконечную вертикальную бегущую строку

Tags: javascript, html, css

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать зацикленную вертикальную строку.
Разметка:

```
<div class="whats-playing__text">
    <p class="whats-playing__how whats-playing__how_purp">КАК ИГРАТЬ?</p>
    <p class="whats-playing__how whats-playing__how_purp-bord">КАК ИГРАТЬ?</p>
    <p class="whats-playing__how whats-playing__how_green">КАК ИГРАТЬ?</p>
    <p class="whats-playing__how whats-playing__how_black">КАК ИГРАТЬ?</p>
    <p class="whats-playing__how whats-playing__how_purp">КАК ИГРАТЬ?</p>
    <p class="whats-playing__how whats-playing__how_purp-bord">КАК ИГРАТЬ?</p>
    <p class="whats-playing__how whats-playing__how_green">КАК ИГРАТЬ?</p>
    <p class="whats-playing__how whats-playing__how_black">КАК ИГРАТЬ?</p>
</div>
```

Важно чтобы контейнер "whats-playing__text" оставался абсолютным.
Пробовал делать так, но анимация обрывается на пол пути.
Также важно, чтобы при достижении строкой конца блока, она возвращалась сверху.

```
@keyframes matrix {
0% {
    transform: translatey(-50%);
 }
100% {
    transform: translatey(0%);
 }
}

.whats-playing__text{
    animation: matrix 4s linear infinite;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понял, то нужно сделать так:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@keyframes matrix {
  0% {
    transform: translatey(-100vh);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translatey(calc(100vh + 100%));
  }
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.whats-playing__text {
  animation: matrix 4s linear infinite backwards;
}
```

```html
<div class="whats-playing__text">
    <p class="whats-playing__how whats-playing__how_purp">КАК ИГРАТЬ?</p>
    <p class="whats-playing__how whats-playing__how_purp-bord">КАК ИГРАТЬ?</p>
    <p class="whats-playing__how whats-playing__how_green">КАК ИГРАТЬ?</p>
    <p class="whats-playing__how whats-playing__how_black">КАК ИГРАТЬ?</p>
    <p class="whats-playing__how whats-playing__how_purp">КАК ИГРАТЬ?</p>
    <p class="whats-playing__how whats-playing__how_purp-bord">КАК ИГРАТЬ?</p>
    <p class="whats-playing__how whats-playing__how_green">КАК ИГРАТЬ?</p>
    <p class="whats-playing__how whats-playing__how_black">КАК ИГРАТЬ?</p>
</div>
```

#### Объяснение

Я сделал так, чтобы анимация шла с начала страницы до её конца (по вертикали), использовал для этого `vh` (`1vh` = 1% от высоты экрана). Я сделал `translatey(calc(100vh + 100%))`, чтобы также скрылся сам элемент. Также добавил к анимации пропорцию `backwards`, оно значит то, что при окончании анимации, элемент будет приведён к его стандартному положению ([Пример на MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation)). `<body>` я добавил `overflow: hidden`, чтобы скрыть элементы вышедшие за пределы документа.

## Исправление

Вот решение которые вроде бы должно вам подойти:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@keyframes matrix {
  0% {
    transform: translatey(-100vh);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translatey(calc(100vh + 100%));
  }
  100% {
    transform: translatey(-100vh);
  }
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.whats-playing__text {
  animation: matrix 4s linear infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="whats-playing__text">
    <p class="whats-playing__how whats-playing__how_purp">КАК ИГРАТЬ?</p>
    <p class="whats-playing__how whats-playing__how_purp-bord">КАК ИГРАТЬ?</p>
    <p class="whats-playing__how whats-playing__how_green">КАК ИГРАТЬ?</p>
    <p class="whats-playing__how whats-playing__how_black">КАК ИГРАТЬ?</p>
    <p class="whats-playing__how whats-playing__how_purp">КАК ИГРАТЬ?</p>
    <p class="whats-playing__how whats-playing__how_purp-bord">КАК ИГРАТЬ?</p>
    <p class="whats-playing__how whats-playing__how_green">КАК ИГРАТЬ?</p>
    <p class="whats-playing__how whats-playing__how_black">КАК ИГРАТЬ?</p>
</div>
```

Если и это вам не подошло, то может тогда такое решение вам подойдёт?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@keyframes matrix {
  0% {
    transform: translatey(-100vh);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translatey(calc(100vh - 100%));
  }
  100% {
    transform: translatey(-100vh);
  }
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.whats-playing__text {
  animation: matrix 4s linear infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="whats-playing__text">
    <p class="whats-playing__how whats-playing__how_purp">КАК ИГРАТЬ?</p>
    <p class="whats-playing__how whats-playing__how_purp-bord">КАК ИГРАТЬ?</p>
    <p class="whats-playing__how whats-playing__how_green">КАК ИГРАТЬ?</p>
    <p class="whats-playing__how whats-playing__how_black">КАК ИГРАТЬ?</p>
    <p class="whats-playing__how whats-playing__how_purp">КАК ИГРАТЬ?</p>
    <p class="whats-playing__how whats-playing__how_purp-bord">КАК ИГРАТЬ?</p>
    <p class="whats-playing__how whats-playing__how_green">КАК ИГРАТЬ?</p>
    <p class="whats-playing__how whats-playing__how_black">КАК ИГРАТЬ?</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Немного не так, мне нужно чтобы когда строка долетала до конца, она возвращалась сверху

Comment: @Tem_Dem в смысле когда она доходит до низа, медленно поднимать её вверх?

Comment: @Tem_Dem Добавил ещё два варианта. Если мой ответ решил ваш вопрос, то прошу отметить его галочкой, она находится рядом с голосами, слева сверху от ответа.

Comment: Не поднимать вверх, а чтобы при достижении конца блока, она была уже сверху (незаметно для пользователя)

Comment: У Вас просто анимация визуально не бесконечная: сперва появляется пустое пространство, а потом она как бы прыгает в начало. Автор вопроса же хочет (судя по всему), чтобы это был по сути вертикальный слайдер

Comment: @Tem_Dem так первый вариант решения так и делает :)

Comment: Да, скорее как вертикальный слайдер

Comment: @humster_spb хммм, ну тогда придётся делать элемент дубликат чтобы можно было сделать "бесконечный" эффект.

Comment: @Tem_Dem постарайтесь сразу объяснять свою мысль в вопросе, чтобы не случалось таких казусов :). По вопросу, мой ответ абсолютно точно подходит, если же вам нужно что-то типа слайдера, то тогда создавайте отдельный вопрос по этому (и не забудьте уточнить подробности перед публикацией вопроса!).

Answer (score 0):

Но ведь есть специальный и любимый всеми тэг...

```html
<marquee direction="down" class="whats-playing__text">
  <p class="whats-playing__how whats-playing__how_purp">КАК ИГРАТЬ?</p>
  <p class="whats-playing__how whats-playing__how_purp-bord">КАК ИГРАТЬ?</p>
  <p class="whats-playing__how whats-playing__how_green">КАК ИГРАТЬ?</p>
  <p class="whats-playing__how whats-playing__how_black">КАК ИГРАТЬ?</p>
  <p class="whats-playing__how whats-playing__how_purp">КАК ИГРАТЬ?</p>
  <p class="whats-playing__how whats-playing__how_purp-bord">КАК ИГРАТЬ?</p>
  <p class="whats-playing__how whats-playing__how_green">КАК ИГРАТЬ?</p>
  <p class="whats-playing__how whats-playing__how_black">КАК ИГРАТЬ?</p>
</marquee>
```